# Selecting rss tags containing ':' with hxt

Tags: css, haskell, rss, hxt

I'm trying to parse some rss that looks like

```
<itunes:duration>01:57:45</itunes:duration>
```

When I try

```
doc >>> css "itunes:duration" /> getText
```

I get

```
*** Exception: src/Text/HandsomeSoup.hs:(79,9)-(84,35): Non-exhaustive patterns in function makePseudo
```

I feel like it's probably something to do with hxt reading the colon as a HandsomeSoup css selector, but I know very little about css. Is there some way to escape it or something I'm missing?

Comment: I am a bit confused why you are using css in an rss-file, I think you are going it the wrong direction. If I recall correctly `itunes` is the schema name in the xml file, and has nothing to do with css (i.e. formatting colors and so on).

Comment: it would be nice to see what you would like to get from a given input.

Comment: Still not sure what was going wrong, but I got the desired result (extracting the contents of the tag) with `doc >>> multi ( hasName "itunes:duration") /> getText`